# viewing file's content for each file-name appearing in a list

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm creating a list of file-names using the command:

```
ls | grep "\.txt$"
```

I'm getting a list of files:

```
F1.txt
F2.txt
F3.txt
F4.txt
```

I want to view the content of these files (using less / more / cat /...)

is there a way to do this by pipping?

(Btw, I got a list of file-names using a more complex command, this is just a simpler example for clarification)

Comment: How do you want to view these files? All at once?

Comment: @squiguy yes, all at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be enough?

```
$ cat *txt
```

For richer queries, you could use `find` and `xargs`:

```
$ find . -name "*txt" | xargs cat
```

Comment: No, I actually got the list with more complicated criterions, this is just an example. I want to know if it's possible to do cat for a *given* list of files.

Comment: @cookya, I see; update my answer, hopefully in the right direction.

Comment: Actually this helps. When I do " | cat *" for the result, I'm getting what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.txt
do
  echo Displaying file $i ...
  more  $i
done
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
cat $(ls | grep "\.txt$")
```